# Copy files to directory in the same structure without the parent folder

Tags: find, cp

I have a few `.html` files that I need to copy from one place to another.

The source folder has files other than `.html`, so I need to first find only the `.html` files and then copy them to the other directory while I maintain the same structure.

Something like this:

```bsh
cp --parents `find ./src -name '*.html'` ./dist
```

The problem is that the files are placed inside `./dist/src/**/*.js` and not `./dist/**/*.js`.

So to summarize, I want to copy all of the files (while maintaining folder structure) from one folder to another without the source parent folder.

For example:

```
src/
  folder1/
    a.html
    a.x
  folder2/
    folder3/
      b.html
```

to

```
dist/
  folder1/
    a.html
  folder2/
    folder3/
      b.html
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rsync -rmv --include='*/' --include='*.html' --exclude='*' src/ dest
```

-r to recurse, -m to prune empty directories, -v verbose.
By default, rsync copies everything, so we include only files with .html suffix and exclude everything else. `--include='*/'` is present to force rsync to descent into directories, without it it does not copy anything. The trailing `/` after src is important so that src itself is not copied into dest.

Look at `man rsync` if you want mode, ownership, etc to be copied as well and add relevant option.

Comment: You are right. Edited. Why would I want to use `-a`? `-r` is sufficient.

Comment: Well, it preserves much of the meta-data associated with the files that are copied, and also won't skip symbolic links and other non-regular files. It may not always be needed.